# Put files in console comand line in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Hi I want to transfer to `main(argc, argv [])` na me of 2 files to work with them. For example in Linux would be `./program file1 file2` but I dont know how windows cmd works and I want to put it in Visual Studio.

Comment: The `main` function and the `argc` and `argv` arguments to the `main` function are *standardized*. They should work exactly the same on *all* systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows it is exactly the same thing. argv[0] is the name of your executable so in this case it will be `program.exe` and the other arguments for your files' names. 
To execute this for a windows command prompt type :

```
program.exe file1 file2
```

If you want it to execute it from visual studio right click on your project choose **properties -> debugging** and add file1 and file2 to your **command arguments**

Answer (score 0):

go to your program's folder via the cmd and type

```
program file1 file2
```